# keyboard buttons in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, gwt

I am trying to multi-select rows from grid and I did it with the code below:

```
public void selectMultipleRows(Integer... indeces) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indeces.length; i++) {
        keyboard().keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
        selectSingleRow(indeces[i]);
        keyboard().keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
    }
}
```

My question is, why I should write `keyboard().keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);` twice?
If I write it once it doesn't work well.

Comment: How does selectSingleRow() work?

Answer (score 1):

May be your first call to `keyboard().keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)` activates `CONTROL` key and second one de-activates it. Again in next iteration, same is repeated. If you remove second call, in next iteration, it de-activates `CONTROL` key and that is why it does not work. Try shifting that line out of loop.

```
public void selectMultipleRows(Integer... indeces) {
    keyboard().keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
    for (int i = 0; i < indeces.length; i++) {
        selectSingleRow(indeces[i]);
    }
}
```